# Extract fields from logs with awk and aggregate them for a new command

Tags: awk, grep, zsh, cut

I have this kind of log:

```
2018-10-05 09:12:38 286 <190>1 2018-10-05T09:12:38.474640+00:00 app web - - Class uuid=uuid-number-one cp=xxx action='xxxx'
2018-10-05 10:11:23 286 <190>1 2018-10-05T10:11:23.474640+00:00 app web - - Class uuid=uuid-number-two cp=xxx action='xxxx'
```

I need to extract `uuid` and run a second query with:

`./getlogs --search 'uuid-number-one OR uuid-number-two'`

For the moment for the first query I do this to extract `uuid`:

`./getlogs | grep 'uuid' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="="} { print $2 }' | cut -d' ' -f1`

My three question :

- I think I could get rid of `grep` and `cut` and use only `awk`?
- How could I capture only the value of `uuid`. I tried `awk '/uuid=\S*/{ print $1 }'`  or `awk 'BEGIN {FS="uuid=\\S*"} { print $1 }'` but it's a failure.
- How could I aggregate the result and turn it into one shell variable that I can use after for the new command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define two field separators:

```
$ awk -F['= '] '/uuid/{print $12}' file
```

Result:

```
uuid-number-one
uuid-number-two
```

Question 2:

The pattern part in awk just selects lines to process. It doesn't change the internal variables like `$1` or `NF`. You need to do the replacement afterwards:

```
$ awk '/uuid=/{print gensub(/.*uuid=(\S*).*/, "\\1", "")}' file
```

Question 3:

```
var=$(awk -F['= '] '/uuid/{r=r","$12}END{print substr(r,2)}' file)
```

Implement the actual aggregation for each line (here `r=r","$12`).

Comment: It works well. On zsh I had to run `setopt +o nomatch` before to avoid error. But it's work perfectly on bash.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following(tested on shown samples and in BASH environment).

```
awk 'match($0,/uuid=[^ ]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5)}'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** In case your `uid` is not having space in it then use following.

```
awk '{sub(/.*uuid=/,"");sub(/ .*/,"")} 1'  Input_file
```

***solution 3rd:*** using `sed` following may help you(considering that uid is not having any space in its values).

```
sed 's/\(.*uuid=\)\([^ ]*\)\(.*\)/\2/'  Input_file
```

***Solution 4th:*** using `awk` field separator method for shown samples.

```
awk -F'uuid=| cp' '{print $2}'  Input_file
```

To concatenate all values into a shell variable use following.

```
shell_var=$(awk 'match($0,/uuid=[^ ]*/){val=val?val OFS substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5):substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5)} END{print val}'  Input_file)
```

Comment: @Mio, I added solution at last to have the all uids values and print them in last, assign them into a shell variable too, let me know if you have any queries here too.

Comment: it works well. I found the other answer a little bit more readable but your answer is valid too! Thanks